# Replace a line selected by a value to an other line selected by a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from quilt.data.bussiere import test
ar = numpy.array([[1.1, 2, 3.3, 4], [2.7, 10, 5.4, 7], [5.3, 9, 1.5, 15]])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar, index = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df.loc[df['A'] == 5.3] = df.loc[df['A'] == 2.7] 
df
```

And the result is a line of NaN :

```
     A        B      C       D
a1  1.1     2.0     3.3     4.0
a2  2.7     10.0    5.4     7.0
a3  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

How to replace it correctly ?

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: add more specifically what you want to do if `df['A] == 5.3`?

Comment: This kind of replacement is going to be extremely problematic. There's no guarantee that `df[df['A'] == 5.3]` and `df[df['A'] == 2.7]` return objects of the same length, so you're likely going to struggle with `ValueError`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` is index sensitive both `df.loc[df['A'] == 5.3]` and `df.loc[df['A'] == 2.7]` are `pandas` `object` , so that `index` will be taken into consideration when you do assign , since one of is index is a2 the other is a3, that is why you received `NaN`

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 5.3] = df.loc[df['A'] == 2.7] .values # using value here,without the index match assign
df
Out[137]: 
      A     B    C    D
a1  1.1   2.0  3.3  4.0
a2  2.7  10.0  5.4  7.0
a3  2.7  10.0  5.4  7.0
```